# Decimal increment for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

could any one explain me the output of this code:

```
num = 0
for i in range(3): # or while True:
    num += 0.1
    print(num)
```

the output:

```
> 0.1
> 0.2
> 0.30000000000000004
```

Comment: See https://0.30000000000000004.com

Comment: why the third output is: 0.30000000000000004
not just : 0.3

Comment: That site explains this